# how to pass parameters to the closure if use @DelegatesTo annotation?

Tags: groovy, groovydsl

if i change the code in [Groovy DSL Doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) here.

add some string 'hello world' to email, like this

```
email('hello world') { // change here
   from 'dsl-guru@mycompany.com'
   to 'john.doe@waitaminute.com'
   subject 'The pope has resigned!'
   body {
      p 'Really, the pope has resigned!'
   }
}
```

and change

```
def email(def name, @DelegatesTo(EmailSpec) Closure cl) {  // change here
    def email = new EmailSpec()
    def code = cl.rehydrate(email, this, this)
    code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    code.call(name) // change here
}
```

so, how to modify the class EmailSpec to get the string 'hello world' ??

Answer (score 1):

To tell the compile that the closure will be called with a parameter you need to add the [`ClosureParams`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/stc/ClosureParams.html) annotation.

To stick with your example:

```
def email(def name,
        @ClosureParams(value = SimpleType, options = "java.lang.String")
        @DelegatesTo(EmailSpec) Closure cl) {
    def email = new EmailSpec()
    def code = cl.rehydrate(email, this, this)
    code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    code.call(name) // change here
}
```

will tell the compiler that the first parameter is a `String`.

For more details have a look at the section [The @ClosureParams annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#_the_code_closureparams_code_annotation) in the groovy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i found a way, but not perfect.

Simple

```
new EmailSpec(name)  // change to
```

however, i really want to use groovy function call(name) to solve it